# Convert date in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS to start of day using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a column of string data type that represents a date. The date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS'. I want to truncate this date to the start of day. So form example,

`2011-07-19 12:44:42.453` should become `2011-07-19 00:00:00.0`

I have tried the following `trunc(record_timestamp,'DD')` but it just gives me blank string. 
I also tried `date_trunc(record_timestamp, 'DD')` but I got the following exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'date_trunc'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  -

```
scala> spark.sql(s""" select "2011-07-19 12:44:42.453" as TS, concat(substring("2011-07-19 12:44:42.453", 0,10), " 00:00:00.0") as TS_Start_Of_Day """).show(false)
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|TS                     |TS_Start_Of_Day      |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|2011-07-19 12:44:42.453|2011-07-19 00:00:00.0|
+-----------------------+---------------------+
```